# Fade image to grayscale in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I'm using expression blend and can't figure out how to go about fading a color image to grayscale. Can I do it in the xaml or do I need to handle this in my C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple ways to do it.

1) pre-compute gray-scale image; place it on top of the color image; animate opacity of the gray scale image from 0 to 1 to get the desired effect.

2) use pixel shader. wpf shader library might have one

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try going option 1) route.